# Is it possible to send a costum message via simple message instead of a trajectory message?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a connection between the abb yumi robot. I know that the simple message connection needs a client on the robot controller and a ros server, that sends the data. Therefore I want to edit the rapid modules. Anyways refering to the title, I just noticed that the Robot Client is used to send trajectories. Is there any way to send a modified message to the rapid server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285405/is-it-possible-to-send-a-costum-message-via-simple-message-instead-of-a-trajectory-message?/) by [moebama](https://answers.ros.org/users/34121/moebama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I just noticed that the Robot Client is used to send trajectories. Is there any way to send a modified message to the rapid server?

This requires a nuanced answer.

Yes, it is possible, if you're willing to edit the sources of `abb_driver` and extend it to be able to deal with your new messages.

No, this is not possible with the current `abb_driver` binaries.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moebama](https://answers.ros.org/users/34121/moebama/) on 2018-03-14**:
Thanks. I worked on that topic today and I know what I have to modify. I'm currently deciding, whether I use the Robot Client nodes and create a costumized message handler or create my own message downloader.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
If I'm not mistaken both options would be about the same work, with the custom downloader needing both an additional socket as well as a bit more work.